# How to properly set up a form that uses multiple entities?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a user creation page that uses User entity form with Username and Email attributes.

I would like when creating a user to be able to choose the tools he will have access to. To do this, retrieve all the tools and display them in a checkbox. Thus, once the form has been validated, the user obtains a username, an email, and the tools to which he has access.

In my User class I can add a tool from the Tool entity using the AddTool() method.

How can I integrate the tools into my user creation form? I don't see how to do I'm lost.

Class User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
     */
    class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180)
         */
        private $username;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="json")
         */
        private $roles = [];
    
        /**
         * @var string The hashed password
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        private $password;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Tool::class, mappedBy="users", fetch="EAGER")
         */
        private $tools;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=125, unique=true)
         */
        private $email;
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->tools = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    
        // SOME FUNCTIONS
    
        /**
         * @return Collection|Tool[]
         */
        public function getTools(): Collection
        {
            return $this->tools;
        }
    
        public function addTool(Tool $tool): self
        {
            if (!$this->tools->contains($tool)) {
                $this->tools[] = $tool;
                $tool->addUser($this);
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function removeTool(Tool $tool): self
        {
            if ($this->tools->removeElement($tool)) {
                $tool->removeUser($this);
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getEmail(): ?string
        {
            return $this->email;
        }
    
        public function setEmail(string $email): self
        {
            $this->email = $email;
    
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

UserType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('email')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply create a ToolType and use a collection of ToolType, https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your UserType buildForm function add something like:

```
$builder
    ->add('username')
    ->add('email')
    ->add('Tools', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Tool::class,
            'multiple' => true
        ])
    ;
```

And You need to create a function in Tool::class definition that will allow display it as a string:

```
#[Pure] public function __toString(): string
    {
        return ''.$this->getFullName();
    }
```

It should allow You to select Tools entities during the generation of User forms.

Comment: Your snippet will only allow selecting one tool.  The requirement is to be able to add multiple tools.

Comment: Does this select tools already owned by the user?
I ask that because on my form it only displayed the word Tools, but nothing else.
I would like to show all the tools and put them in checkbox.

Comment: I will try to edit my answer after work. If I remember correctly You need to define Tools in User as an unmapped field, create a query that selects tools only available to the current user, and generate checkboxes from the result. Meanwhile, can You add Your Tool Class source to the question?